# JBChartView how to add a label to each bar? (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, jbchartview

I'm using the JBChartView library to draw a bar chart in my iOS application. Each Bar should have an identifier, that is shown at the bottom of the bar.
I tried defining a custom barView with an additional label, but do not know how to place the label relative to the bar.

Here's the code:

```
func barChartView(barChartView: JBBarChartView!, barViewAtIndex index: UInt) -> UIView! {
    let barView = UIView()

    // setting up the bar
    let bar: Float = chartData[Int(index)]
    var barColor = UIColorFromRGB(0xE8E8E8)
    if bar >= 1 { barColor = UIColorFromRGB(0xFF6259) }
    if bar > 33 { barColor = UIColorFromRGB(0xFFC02F) }
    if bar > 66 { barColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x28CA41) }
    barView.backgroundColor = barColor

    // setting up the label
    var label = UILabel()
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    label.textColor = barColor
    label.text = NSString(format: "%.0f", bar)
    barview.addSubview(label)

    return barView
}
```

Your help would be much appreciated!

Comment: maybe autolayout with constraints would work? But how to do that in code?

Answer (score 2):

ok, this is embarassing: label and bar had the same color, so the label was there all the time .

The final code (improved and with an additional Data Label):

```
func barChartView(barChartView: JBBarChartView!, barViewAtIndex index: UInt) -> UIView! {
    let barView = BarChartBarView()

    let bar: Float = chartData[Int(index)]
    var barColor = UIColorFromRGB(0xE8E8E8)
    if bar >= 1 { barColor = UIColorFromRGB(0xFF6259) }
    if bar > 33 { barColor = UIColorFromRGB(0xFFC02F) }
    if bar > 66 { barColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x28CA41) }
    barView.backgroundColor = barColor

    barView.dataLabel.text = NSString(format: "%.0f", bar)
    barView.legendLabel.text = chartLegend[Int(index)]

    return barView
}
```

class BarChartBarView: UIView {

```
let labelFont = UIFont(name:"Raleway-Thin", size:8.0)
var padding = CGFloat(0)
var barWidth = CGFloat(27)
var dataLabel = UILabel()
var legendLabel = UILabel()
var legendLabelWidth = CGFloat(50)
var labelHeight = CGFloat(27)

override convenience init() {
    self.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
}


override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    self.backgroundColor = UIColorFromRGB(0xE8E8E8)

    // setting up data Label
    dataLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, barWidth, labelHeight)
    dataLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    dataLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    dataLabel.font = labelFont
    self.addSubview(dataLabel)

    // setting up legend Label
    legendLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.bounds.height, legendLabelWidth, labelHeight)
    legendLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    legendLabel.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    legendLabel.font = labelFont
    self.addSubview(legendLabel)
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    let xOffset = (self.barWidth - self.legendLabelWidth) / 2
    let yOffset:CGFloat = self.bounds.height
    let width = self.legendLabelWidth
    let height = self.labelHeight

    self.legendLabel.frame = CGRectMake(xOffset, yOffset, width, height)
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

@Armin
I got the clue to implement the following method:

```
- (UIView *)barChartView:(JBBarChartView *)barChartView barViewAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
```

From Armin. Because even though JawBone's JBBarChart library is impressive their Demo is totally done using code, and also it's bit confusing at a glance. However my way of adding the Label view is same old way of creating a UIView and adding the UILabel as a subview and returning it. And it looks like follows:

```
- (UIView *)barChartView:(JBBarChartView *)barChartView barViewAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
    UIView *barView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 55, (CGFloat)chartData[(int)index])];
    if (index == 0) {
        [barView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
    } else if (index == 1) {
        [barView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    } else if (index == 2) {
        [barView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
    } else {
        [barView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    }

    int roomCount = (int)chartData[(int)index];
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(2, 5.0f, 50.0f, 21.0f)];
    [label setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
    [label setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [label setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Raleway-Thin" size:6.0]];
    [label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d/56", roomCount]];

    [barView addSubview:label];
    return barView;
}
```

Please consider that **chartData** is contains my data, as integers. So I need the **height of each Bar View** according to that integer in each position.

Hope this answer would be helpful to someone out there, specially who is juggling to do this implementation in Objective-C.

Cheers!